# Better approach to do background processes using Sidekiq and MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, backgroundworker, background-process, sidekiq

I have a service that analyzes e-mails in a list. Each lists can contain 500 to 200,000 emails. The best way I found was to analyze these lists is using Sidekiq services background. It's working, but i don't think this is the best way to analyze these e-mails, the reason is :

The Sidekiq is configured to use threads 25, and i'm using MongoDB to store these emails.

The workflow of the job is:

Search the e-mail in MongoDB using the ID passed via parameters to the job; 
Analyze the e-mail and update the status of the analysis in the database : Valid or Invalid.

So it makes an average of 25 concurrent accesses to the database and after 1 ~ 4 seconds (processing time) it need to access the database again to update the status ( 1 time for each job ).

If a list has 100.000 emails, 100.000 jobs will be needed to complete this task. 200.000 accesses will be made in the database, 25 concurrency in most of time.

This is a good way to perform this service ? Is there a way to perform less access to MongoDB ?

I can not see another way to do this .

Comment: did this end up being performant or did you have to  change it to perform less database access. I am trying to implement something similar, which is why i am asking.